# Recovered/Encrypted DMG File fails to mount

Tags: macos, data-recovery, dmg-image

A 2.3GB encrypted DMG file recovered from my external hdd with DiskDrill (OSX), and getdataback (WIN) but won't mount. I try many ways, diskutil, terminal, 3rd party Software, but no luck.

I know the password, is 100% correct. I would appreciate any help.

I am running BigSur

Comment: The likelihood is it's corrupted. File scavengers are far less successful on encrypted files because there's no discernible pattern to them when scavenging. What error do you get?

Comment: Diskutil warning: no mountable file system.

Comment: Does it get so far as to ask for a password, or is that the first thing you see? I don't really hold high hopes for it, tbh. Might possibly be worth another disk drill scavenge, see if it finds anything different, or another scavenger app, but I don't see it as being too promising, I'm afraid. If it was on an HD with lots of free space, your chances might be better than if the drive was mainly full, or worse still if it was an SSD.

Comment: The disk was about 50% full, and was HDD not SSD.

The problem starts when i was working on terminal, formatting another external HDD (disk1), but my ext. HDD was connected too (disk2).

At this moment i copy paste a line command into terminal but terminal starts formatting immediately without waiting me for pressing "enter" and the disk number that copied was wrong (disk2). So i stop very fast the terminal but the disk was already change the name volume. I think none of data was damaged, i recover everything 100%, all data is working except this file -because- it is encrypted (i guess).